# <ajaxToolkit:ReorderList> is not draggable in IE8 and chrome

Tags: internet-explorer-8, reorderlist

ajaxtoolkit ReorderList is not working in IE 8.Can not drag it in IE 8.But It is working in IE 7 and Fire fox.Please help me.I want to make it to work in IE 8.That is my client requirement.I have done lot of developments on this an it is not possible to turn to another one.

Comment: I am unable to reorder my records in internet explorer.

Comment: Just FYI, it doesnt work in Chrome either :)

You sure you can't just implement your own control, exposing the same properties you are using on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I updated AjaxControlToolkit with latest available version AjaxControlToolkit 3.0.30930.0
Now it is working fine.

Thanks